# Meeting request in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, email

I will receive meeting.ics (VCS/ICS calendar attachment) from my manager , previously I had some add-on in Thunderbird which was working fine . After some updates the meetings.ics file become as attachment , its not automatically added to calender?

What is the issue ? How can this be resolved?

*Edit 2 : I have  the Lightning Project, an extension also*

Comment: none of the answer is solving my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could add a bit more information - what version of Thunderbird are you using? What version of Lightning are you using? What was the update (or updates) that caused the problem? What addon(s) are you using apart from Lightning?

Using [Thunderbird 2.0](http://www.mozillamessaging.com) and [Lightning 0.9](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning) this works for me. You could [backup your profile](http://www.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/profile), uninstall the Lightning addon, uninstall Thunderbird, then reinstall [Thunderbird 2.0](http://www.mozillamessaging.com) and the [Lightning 0.9](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning) addon.

Comment: This is may not be perfect solution . But works for me ;)

Comment: Glad to help! Lets hope these things become more reliable in subsequent releases.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known problem with the Thunderbird/Lightning combination. There is a small workaround though found [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=830845):

> You need to set "display attachments
>   inline", then you can accept or
>   decline invites though a button at the
>   top of the email-preview. You can
>   also drag the ics-attachment to the
>   calendar-button in the mode-toolbar.
>   Lightning doesn't register itself as
>   the default program for .ics files
>   (yet).

Comment: This is work around also not working . and  I am not able the slove issue with this answer

Comment: I have setted to display attachements inline also not working and drag and drop also not working

Comment: What happens when you use thunderbird without lightning?

Comment: Its still attachment

Comment: I'd suggest trying an old version to see if the problem persists, it can help you pinpoint which version has this bug and you can then report it to Mozilla. You can find all old versions here: http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/

Comment: I've been using the drag-and-drop workaround for a while, does it not prompt you when you do a drag and drop ?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that something has changed on your manager's side? I believe this option needs to be selected in Outlook 2003:

Tools > Options > Calendar Options... > When sending meeting requests over the Internet, use iCalendar format

Comment: Manager's they never change any thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use lightening (unless it installed automatically with thunderbird 3) but I use outlook, and i find that Thunderbird thinks .ics files are text files and cannot handle them properly. If I tell it to open with outlook it opens an email with the file attached to send. The only work around I have found is to save the attachment (I do it to desktop) then open it, and windows knows what to do with it.

why cant the programmers either let windows handle attachments like it used to in the old versions, or allow the user to add file types so that it knows .ics is an outlook calendar file (in my case)?.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Thunderbird 3.0.10, and Lightning 1.0b2pre.  When I receive an Outlook email invite I see a `meeting.ics` attachment, which can be viewed (and that's all) by checking `View->Display Attachments inline`.

In order to get these into my Lightning calendar, I have to save the attachment, then use `Events and Tasks->Import` and choose the saved `meeting.ics`.  This works!  I can then open the event, update it, and once it's in the calendar I even see the buttons accept, etc.

Whew!

Answer (score -1):

For as long as I have used the Lightning addon for Thunderbird, that has been the behavior.  Meetings don't get automatically added to the calendar.  When they are accepted they are added.

The .ics file has always been an attachment.  Thunderbird may render that fact differently depending on the plug-ins you have installed.