# Thunderbird not accepting meeting requests

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I am currently using Thunderbird 2.0.0.23, I can successfully send meeting requests to all types of calendars however when someone sends me a meeting request and I want to either accept or decline the meeting error number: MODIFICATION_Failed appears. I have also installed Lightning 0.9 but the same error is repeating

Any ideas?
Inge

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/24069/meeting-request-in-thunderbird

Comment: not a dupe, he wanted them automatically added to calendar. OP on this question can't even accept requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug which has recently fixed, you can find details on it [**here**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392465). The most recent version of lightning will fix this (See [**Systech's answer**](https://superuser.com/questions/51748/thunderbird-not-accepting-meeting-requests/51750#51750) for links).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, i downloaded the beta versions and this seems to solve the problem

Thunderbird 3 Beta 3: http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/early_releases/

Lightning 1.0pre: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/calendar/lightning/nightly/latest-comm-1.9.1/ (Warning: This is a development snapshot: It contains the latest changes, but may also have severe known issues, including data loss situations. In fact, it may not work at all.

Source <[forums.mozillazine.org](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=7279445&sid=23fd9291c2bdedc4ff9a27075cab5871#p7279445)>

Comment: You may want to reference your source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=7279445&sid=23fd9291c2bdedc4ff9a27075cab5871#p7279445

Comment: @ John T This has been updated