# In Mozilla Thunderbird, how to attach an event to an email?

Tags: email, thunderbird, calendar, ics, lightning

In Mozilla Thunderbird, how to attach an event to an email?

Basically, I need to do the opposite of what's described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/382022/how-do-i-get-thunderbird-to-open-an-ics-attachment-directly-in-lightnings-calen): I need to create an event in Lightning, and then attach it to an email in Thunderbird.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that the following works, though there may be neater solutions:-

1. Right-cling on the event and select **Copy**.
2. Open a text editor and select new, right-click and paste.
3. Save the file as `EventName.ics` and attach this to your e-mail.

Your recipient will then have to save and import, as described in your link.

Comment: Many thanks! I was hoping for a simpler/more straightforward solution, until there is, this trick will be extremely useful. Thanks again! Martin